# seeing junk characters in google drive folder in double comander

Tags: google-drive, double-commander

i use linux mint 19.1 tessa desktop.

enabled google drive as online account in preferences. can now see google drive folder & files as a network drive in nemo.

i use double commander for several file transfer requirements. can see the google drive as a network drive in double commander, but as soon as i click on this drive, i see only some junk characters, instead of file & folder names.

does anyone here know why this could be happening ?

Comment: The title says Total Commander and the question Double Commander. These are two totally different programs (I guess that you mean DC, as you are on Linux?)

Comment: thanks for pointing out my mistake. just corrected the title.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the names are scrambled and usable only by the Nautilus plugin.
I did hide the disk adding it to the drive-blacklist under Configuration->Behaviors. The value to put is: google-drive://your.name@gmail.com/